# jqueryui datepicker, compare two dates and adjust if greater or less than

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to make a dateRange of two inputs **sdate** and **edate**, but if sdate becomes greater than edate, I want edate to be set to what sdate is selected as, and vice versa.

### An example would be:

If both sdate and edate are set to '2014-08-02', if I edate to '2014-08-01', sdate should move to '2014-08-01'. However, setting edate to '2014-08-03' should do nothing but change edate.

Should work in a similar fashion if sdate is greater than edate.

EDIT: Updated the jsfiddle with an improvement. I can get the edate to change when I go passed it with the sdate, but I can't get the edate to change if it's less than the sdate. [Here's a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/a4fb9fxq/2/)

```
function dateRange() {
     $(function () {
     $("#sdate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        defaultDate: "+0d",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function () {
            testDates();
        }
    });
    $("#sdate").datepicker("setDate", "set");
    $("#edate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        defaultDate: "+0d",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function () {
            testDates();
        }
    });
    $("#edate").datepicker("setDate", "set");
});
function testDates() {
    var sdate = $("#sdate").datepicker("getDate");
    var edate = $("#edate").datepicker("getDate");
    if (sdate > edate) {
        $("#sdate").datepicker("setDate", sdate);
        $("#edate").datepicker("setDate", sdate);
    }else if (edate < sdate) {
        $("#sdate").datepicker("setDate", edate);
        $("#edate").datepicker("setDate", edate);
     }
}
}
```

Comment: And are you having problems?

Comment: Yes, the date range works fine, normally, but I can't get the date ranges to change if sdate or edate are lesser or greater than each other. sdate should not be greater than edate, and edate should not be less than sdate. They should function normally if the dates are valid for a normal date range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by building a conditional into the function.

```
function dateRange() {
    $(function () {
        $("#sdate,#edate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            defaultDate: "+0d",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        }).change(function () {
            var sdate = $('#sdate').datepicker("getDate");
            var edate = $('#edate').datepicker("getDate");
            if (this.id == 'sdate') {
                if (sdate > edate) {
                    $('#edate').datepicker("setDate", sdate);
                }
            } else {
                if (edate < sdate) {
                    $('#sdate').datepicker("setDate", edate);
                }
            }
        });
        $("#sdate,#edate").datepicker("setDate", "set");
    });
}
```

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmac25/udtmn6n7/

Answer (score 1):

try this it's working. if you need anything more please let me.

```
  $(function () {
        $("#sdate,#edate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            defaultDate: "+0d",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,

            onClose: function () {
                //testDates();
            }
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            $('#edate,#sdate').val($(this).val());
        });
        $("#sdate,#edate").datepicker("setDate", "set");
    });
```

see jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav22031987/tuG6C/216/

Comment: Hello gaurav, thank you for your suggestion. However, my goal is to only change the value if the sdate or edate exceed each other. So, if sdate and edate are 2014-08-02. If I set edate to 2014-08-01, sdate should change to 2014-08-01, and vice versa if sdate is greater than edate. Otherwise, they should function independent of each other and allow me to create date ranges.